# Is it possible to locate used code in xcode during testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

This may sound confusing, so I'll do my best to explain it. I am using Xcode and Swift.

I was wondering if it's possible to view which code is being used at specific times, e.g. when I press a button or use an action in a view.

I have some code and can test it in the simulator, but I don't know exactly what part of the ViewController files it is using. I'd like to know which methods/functions are being called when I do specific tasks.

IS there any way to do this without using a hundred `print("Random Text")` ?

Thanks!

Comment: if you don't want nslogs or prints then use a debugger - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141008/how-to-trace-program-execution-in-xcode

Comment: I would put a breakpoint at the beginning of each method.